# Error with r.reclass on QGIS for Mac

Tags: qgis, mac, reclassify

I'm trying to use r.reclass fonction (grass7) on QGIS (2.18.15) for Mac but when I ran it, there was an error :

**[Errno 13] Permission denied: u'tmp152292116024' See log for more details**

I searched to solve it but I didn't find anything...
Somebody can help me ?

[image]
[image]